# Error when executing the npx create-nuxt-app command

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I tried to execute the

```
npx create-nuxt-app nuxt
```

command. But there was an error:

[image: error]

**Path to npm-cache without spaces**. Everything used to work fine, at least with `vue create` command.

- *Maybe update node js npm/npx ?*
- *Maybe there is no support for conditional export in node js v12-14 ? Maybe make a downgrade to node js v10 ?*

Comment: try to update your node to 14.x, or try to run terminal as administrator.

Comment: I found out that conditional export support is available in versions from 13.8, I had 13.5. Now im will check

Comment: So. Yeah! Problem is decided! Indeed, there is support for conditional export in version 13.8 and higher.